# Prove that Hall's Condition is necessary for complete matching

Tags: graph-theory, proof-verification

Here's what I have so far:

Hall's Algorithm states that given $n$ girls and $n$ boys a complete matching between the two groups is possible iff any of the three conditions are satisfied:

1. There is no $r\times s$ sub matrix of zeros s.t. $r+s>n$,
2. Every set of $r$ girls likes at least $r$ boys,
3. Every set of $s$ boys likes at least $s$ girls.

Proof: Assume by contradiction that there is an $r\times s$ sub matrix of zeros s.t. $r+s>n$.  This means that less than $n$ rows or columns have been crossed off or that there are less than $n$ complete matchings possible.  Hence it will not be possible that every set of $r$ girls or $s$ boys likes at least $r$ boys or $s$ girls.  Therefore it is possible to find at least one column in a combination of rows and/or columns s.t. condition 2) and 3) are not fulfilled.

Is there anything that should be changed?

Comment: submatrix of what?

Comment: sub matrix of zeros created after you cross out all the ones. in the matrix

Comment: But what is **the** matrix your submatrix is a submatrix of?

Comment: submatrix is of zeros left over after the matrix of zeros and ones have been crossed out.  Crossing out all the ones on rows and/or columns should produce a sub matrix of zeros.  At the same time the number of crosses tells us how many complete marriages are possible.

Comment: the matrix of zeros and ones tells us which girl is matched to which boy.  So say if girl 1 was matched to boy 2, then there will be a 1 on the entry (1,2) of the matrix.  It is possible for girls to be matched to multiple boys and vice versa.